# Problem with shapefile created using Arcgis 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, encoding, arabic

I have create  a **shapefile** using **Arcgis 10.3** . the **shapefile** contains attribute data in **Arabic language** . the problem came when I open it in **Mapwell** (an app  specializes in creating navigable maps) **Mapwell** displays it as series of question marks and other symbols , even if I set the **encoding** to Arabic . 
Here another I have noticed , When I export the same data using **Arcgis 10.0** it just works flawlessly.

I did some workarounds like changing the encoding scheme of some files (**.cpg** and **.dbf**) and other things, and nothing has worked

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it happen because of system different language, you can solve display right to left languages character such as Persian and Arabic when you "change system locate..." language in "Region and language" in Windows OS.

1. Go to control panel
2. Find Region and Language
3. Select Administrative Tab
4. Language for Non-unicode programs
   and change current Language for Non-unicode program to Arabic.
5. After that restart your system.

[image]

Comment: Sorry  , It doesn't work

Comment: Ok I recommend convert ArcGIS output to unicode: open registory editor (type regedit in run) or search regedit.exe in windows folder, after that  find and open below address in registry Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI choose New from Edit menu and select Key, Type "Common" for new key and press Enter create another key inside "common" and call it "CodePage" and then choose "CodePage" and create "string value" change name to "dbfDefault" and then right click on it and choose modify and finally change "Value Data" to "UTF-8" eventually restart your system.